# Raspberry Pi UART TX/RX loop delay

Tags: c, unix, raspberry-pi, uart

I'm attempting to use an RPi to communicate with a commercial microcontroller via UART. The ultimate goal is a feedback control system, but as a first step, I'm trying to get the following loop working:

- RPi transmits command 1 on TX pin to the external controller (48 bytes)
- RPi receives response to command 1 on the RX pin (48 bytes)
- RPi transmits command 2 on TX pin to the external controller (48 bytes)
- RPi receives response to command 2 on the RX pin (48 bytes)
- RPi transmits command 3 on TX pin to the external controller (48 bytes)
- RPi receives response to command 3 on the RX pin (48 bytes)

. . . etc.

I've managed to successfully read and write to the UART using the following code, but I'm still getting some weird behavior that's causing the loop to get out of sync:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    setup_uart(); // init uart

    int test_val = 123;

    int j = 0;
    while( 1 ){
        delayMicroseconds( 8900 );
        tx_value(test_val+j);
        rx_value();
        ++j;
    }
}
```

The `tx_value` and `rx_value` methods make calls to the generic UNIX system call `write` and `read` methods, respectively, using the method described [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/using-the-uart):

```
void rx_value() {
    if (uart0_filestream != -1)
    {
        // read up to 48 bytes
        rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 48);
    }
}
```

The UART is configured as follows:

```
void setup_uart(void) {
    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); 
    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
    options.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;   //<Set baud rate 115200
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;

    tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
}
```

When running the code as listed, I'm not getting the desired send/receive loop. All the data is there, but it looks something like

- RPi transmits command 1 on TX pin to the external controller (48 bytes)
- RPi receives part of response to command 1 on the RX pin (8 bytes)
- RPi transmits command 2 on TX pin to the external controller (48 bytes)
- RPi receives rest of response to command 1 on the RX pin (40 bytes)
- RPi transmits command 3 on TX pin to the external controller (48 bytes)
- RPi receives response to command 2 on the RX pin (48 bytes)

. . . etc. I.e., there's a delay of one cycle between TX and RX, which is non-ideal for my desired control infrastructure.

I have already tried the following hacks/mitigation techniques, and many permutations thereof:

- sending, then reading twice on the first loop --> the first packet just gets further divided, resulting in the same delayed loop
- setting `options.c_cc[VMIN]` in both blocking and non-blocking mode --> when set to 0, first RX receives 0 bytes, and remaining calls receive 48 --> same steady-state loop as above; when set to 8, same steady-state loop as above; when set to 48, program hangs
- increasing the call to delayMicroseconds to several seconds --> no change in behavior

I've also looked at the TX/RX pins using a logic analyzer, and there's more time between the first TX/RX call and the others, but there are no breaks within the 48-byte transmissions themselves, so I'm not sure why the first RX call can only receive up to 8 of the bytes. I've been doing some research on how the `read` command works, but it's such a low-level system call that I'm not sure how to approach the problem. Can anyone offer any insight as to why this might be happening, or any suggestions for alternative methods that might not have this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the protocol of microcontroller designed? Does it have start-stop message markers, or message length in a header? Then you know exactly how much to read or when the received message ends, and can then wait until that before sending the next message. Don't just blindly send the next command without receiving the reply to the previous.

Comment: Another way, if you can control the actual protocol, is to insert a sequence number in it, then you know which received message belongs to which sent message, Should probably be combined with one of the above described methods of knowing when you have received a complete message.

Comment: Why the delay? You send a command and then only read the reply once, before delaying almost 1/100th second and sending another command. Your read function (a/c to doc linked) is non-blocking, ie it only reads whatever number of chars are there (or none). So if only 8 chars have come back, that's what you get. Post `rx_value()`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: All my commands are exactly 48 bytes, so I've been attempting to wait for 48 bytes before sending the next command, e.g., by setting `options.c_cc[VMIN]` to 48, but the program just hangs and I'm not sure why. I've been using the incrementing `test_val` above to match TX to RX like I think you're suggesting with the sequence numbers, and I've been printing the received bytes -- I just took out the print statements for this post. All the data is getting through, it's just delayed.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `rx_value` posted above. I've tried increasing and decreasing the delay value and nothing changes, and I've tried to effect blocking behavior of sorts by setting `VMIN` as described above.

Comment: `read()` will read *up to* 48 chars if you are non-blocking, it does not wait until 48 are there, and neither does your program make an attempt to get 48 chars. Perhaps the delay should be moved between the TX and the RX, pending improvements to the reading? You've done nothing with `rx_length` in function `rx_value()`.

Comment: I think You can can call `read()` multiple times in loop until expected 48 bytes are received.

Comment: or flag, and ask admin to move to raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . Good luck.